# Mutating variables in child component and accessing state in parent component kotlin jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to change the state of a variable in a child component and access the new value in its parent component. I have the below code:

```
enum class View {
    SIGN_IN,
    CREATE_ACCOUNT,
    LOADING
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                var view: MutableState<View> = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(View.LOADING)
                }

                when (view.value) {
                    View.SIGN_IN -> SignIn(view)
                    View.CREATE_ACCOUNT -> CreateAccount(view)
                    else -> { Loading(view = view, accountType = "") }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Loading(view: MutableState<View>, accountType: String) {
    if (accountType == "") {
        view.value = View.CREATE_ACCOUNT
    } 
}
```

The value "" is being passed to `Loading()` as `accountType` so when running `Loading()`, `view.value` is set to `CREATE_ACCOUNT`, which I need reflected in `MainActivity`, so that the `CreateAccount()` component is displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It’s not supposed to be the job of Composables to create side effects. You are trying to have the act of composing the Loading() Composable create a change of state, which is breaking this rule. It’s also poor encapsulation, because the top level Composable that knows about the different states of View is asking Loading to do something on its behalf, so you are spreading across different levels of Composables the need to know about this level of state and how to mutate it—if you do very much of this at all, your code will be like spaghetti and very hard to maintain and keep bug-free.

Comment: If you want something to be loaded on your Loading screen, it should be something that’s done in a ViewModel. The ViewModel can initiate loading on demand and the top level Composable can choose to show the Loading Composable while it is relevant.

Comment: I don't see a question being asked here. What issue are you facing?

Comment: @Tenfour04 @Ricky Mo Thank you for your responses. I was attempting to mutate the value of a variable within a child component and access the changed state in its parent component. If I understand what @Tenfour04 is saying, I should be preforming mutations in the parent component. I tried moving the logic `if (accountType == "") { view.value = View.CREATE_ACCOUNT }` I had in `Loading()` to the `else` line in the `when` statement I have, and now the app is crashing on loading for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the official documentation about [Jetpack Compose UI Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture). Jetpack Compose uses the [unidirectional data flow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf) pattern. So data flows downwards the Composable hierarchy by passing it to child Composables, and events flow up the hierarchy by invoking callback functions.

A simple example for unidirectional data flow would be as follows:

```
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {

    var showTextBoolean by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    ChildComposable(
        showText = showTextBoolean,       // pass variable to child Composable
        onShowTextChange = { newValue ->  // pass callback function to child Composable
            showTextBoolean = newValue    // set updated value received from child Composable
        }
    )  

    if (showTextBoolean) {
        Text(text = "HELLO I AM THE PARENT")
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposable(showText: Boolean, onShowTextChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    if (showText) {
        Text(text = "HELLO I AM THE CHILD")
    }
    Button(onClick = { onShowTextChange(true) }) {  // pass updated data to parent as function parameter
        Text(text = "SHOW TEXT")
    }

}
```

1. The data (`showTextBoolean`) is passed to the child
2. When the child wants to modify the data, it can do so by calling a function in the parent Composable and passes the new value to the parent
3. The parent Composable sets the new value
4. The child Composable will receive the updated value from the parent Composable and will be updated.

This answers the actual question that you mentioned in your title. However, as pointed out in a comment, there might be better ways to handle loading, for example by using a [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#5).